# Cmake ARGV and Macro BUG?

Tags: cmake

The following is strange!

```
macro(foo in1)
  message("FIRST" ${in1})
  message("OPtional1:" ${ARGV1})
  message("OPtional2:" ${ARGV2})
if( NOT ${ARGV1} AND ${ARGV2} )
   message("IF")  
else()
   message("ELSE")  
endif()
endmacro()
```

Running the following:

```
foo("gaga" false true)
```

(SHOULD GIVE "IF")
WORKS!

**BUT**

```
foo("gaga" false)
```

(SHOULD GIVE "ELSE" because the second optional argument is FALSE!)

Results in error:

```
cmake:126 (if):
given arguments:  "NOT" "false" "AND"
Unknown arguments specified
```

Is this a bug??

The following works:

```
if( NOT "${ARGV1}" AND "${ARGV2}" )
   message("IF")  
else()
   message("ELSE")  
endif()
```

WHY???

THANKS For any help!

(With functions it works)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In macros, ARGV1 etc. are not real CMake variables.  Instead, `${ARGV1}` is the string replacement from the macro call.  That means that your call with only one argument expands to

```
if( NOT false AND )
```

which explains the error message.  By enclosing the string expansions in quotes, you now have

```
if( NOT "false" AND "")
```

giving the IF command an empty string to evaluate.  Other solutions: use the ${ARGC} string replacement to decide whether the argument is present before trying to expand ARGV2.  Or, as you've mentioned, switch to a function instead of a macro.  In a function, ARGV1 is an actual CMake variable, and you can write it more sensibly, even without the ${} expansion at all:

```
function(foo in1)
  message("Optional1: " ${ARGV1})
  message("Optional2: " ${ARGV2})
if( NOT ARGV1 AND ARGV2 )
   message("IF")  
else()
   message("ELSE")  
endif()
endfunction()
```

Reference:
http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command:macro

Answer (score 0):

```
if(NOT ARGV1 AND ARGV2)
```

is the same as

```
if(ARGV2 AND NOT ARGV1)
```

Logical negation (and most other unary operators) binds before conjunction.